# Minecraft, reverse default of rail switch w/ button

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a rail with a T-junction. At the junction the user is given a choice of which direction to go. If they push a button they go one way, if they don't push the button they go the other way. My problem is the direction that the rail defaults to when using a button is the opposite of the direction I want it to go if you don't push anything. How can I reverse the default direction of the rail when the button is off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a little more complicated, you could use a `Not Gate`. In a nutshell, a not gate is a logic gate which inverts a signal. Basically, if your lever is outputting a redstone signal, the not gate will not out put the signal.If a lever is in an off state, the not gate will out put a signal, achieving what you are asking.

A not gate is very simple to build. You only need to put a power source (lever, button, etc.) on a block. On any free side of the block (except the bottom face of course) you put a redstone torch. It's that simple. The redstone torch should be touching the rail, and when the lever/button/etc is flipped, the torch should turn off.

Here is an image of a simple NOT gate:
[image: A simple NOT gate]

A version that fits under the ground (notice the half slab):
[image: Underground version]

With this gate, the signal is inverted, therefore changing the default state of the lever/button.

Comment: Thank you! I swear I tried every possible combination but somehow missed this! Thanks for the detailed answer as well!

Comment: Actually I can't get the underground one working.. Do you have more screenshots of it at different angles? I must be missing something. And ya I have the half slab

Comment: @RelicCross That's because slabs do not conduct redstone signal. Instead, the rail block is being powered by stone block, which is original behavior.

Comment: When using a detector rail right next to the track it is not possible to use a NOT gate.. I am interested in the OP's original question. And why does the game seem to arbitrarily decide which directions when powered. It's the opposite of what I want, unfortunately